# Update bootstrap modal title on closing and reopening

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, attributes, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal that is toggled with this  element;

```
<i id="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-title="Title1" data-target="#Modal"></i><span>Open modal</span>
```

When modal is shown the title is set;

```
$('#Modal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
// set title of modal
$("#ModalLabel").html($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'));
});
```

After this I edit the title like this;

```
$("#modal").attr('data-title', "Title2");
```

The data-title attribute of  element is now "Title2" but when closing and reopen the modal the title is unchanged.

How to make jquery refresh the modal title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was editing the title I was only changing the attribute in html. To change the value we need to specify .data for it to update correctly.

```
$("#modal").data('data-title', "Title2");
```